# Issues with jQuery plugin in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, nivo-slider

Just trying to get the nivo slider plugin for jquery working on a basic rails app. Tried the simplest proof of concept I could, just putting the demo into a static html page in the public folder, but I still can't get it to work. Here is the current header I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/demo/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
    <title>Nivo Slider Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/themes/light/light.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/themes/dark/dark.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/themes/bar/bar.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/assets/javascripts/nivo-slider/demo/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>

</head>
```

Every time this loads up in heroku though I get the error: ReferenceError:

```
$ is not defined    

$(window).load(function() {
```

I'm fairly new to web development in general, but I just don't know how to fix this. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is not being loaded. You are using relative paths in rails. If you must manually load your javascripts you should consider using:

You can `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` to manually add it.

---

A better approach is to use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for all javascript.

You have taken out the `javascript_include_tag "application"` code from the layout file which is normally in: `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

You should put it back and then use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to take care of jQuery and your code for you.

Relative paths are allowed in rails, but may not work as expected. Rails only serves assets from the public directory not the vendor directory. Normally you just let rails compile all js/css to one file and it is served out of the `public/assets` directory.

Comment: That line was still in there, but switching to the ajax google remedied that problem. Are relative paths not allowed in rails?

Comment: Cool, thanks! Still not totally able to get the demo to work, but definitely one step closer.

Comment: I had an unrelated issue where using Lightbox2 wasnt working with the latest jQuery 1.10, so i disabled loading jquery-rails plugin via the asset pipeline and used your script tag above to go back to using v1.8.3 instead which works. It sucks i had to do this but it works. thanks.